# MobileNets for a custom image size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to use the MobileNet model pre-trained on ImageNet for feature extraction. I am loading the model as follows:

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet

feature_model = MobileNet(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(200, 200, 3))
```

The Keras manual [clearly says](https://keras.io/applications/#mobilenet) that this input shape is valid:

> input_shape: optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top is False (otherwise the input shape has to be (224, 224, 3) (with 'channels_last' data format) or (3, 224, 224) (with 'channels_first' data format). It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 32. E.g. (200, 200, 3) would be one valid value.

However, I get the following error message:

> ValueError: If imagenet weights are being loaded, input must have a static square shape (one of (128, 128), (160, 160), (192, 192), or (224, 224)). Input shape provided = (200, 200, 3)

Why does it require the input shape to match the one it was trained on if I specify `include_top=False`?

Keras: 2.2.4, TensorFlow: 1.13.1

Update: As @Soroush pointed out, this exception was removed [recently](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/pull/94/commits/9d2664c5df9f2f018637995d6f40ab51d1669b93). However, the issue was not fully resolved as described [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/issues/92#issuecomment-480958268).

Update2: The problem was resolved by these two pull requests ([1](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/pull/94), [2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/pull/101)).

Comment: input shape (200,200,3) is only valid if weights=None and you can assign include_top true or false. For pre-trained weights imagenet is only avilable for listed shapes.

Comment: With `include_top=False`, the model consists of convolutional layers only (no FC layers). Why is it then limited to these shapes? E.g. I can load the VGG16 model using an arbitrary input shape even though it was trained on ImageNet with the shape of (224,224,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is wrong and was recently (Mar 29, 2019) removed from Keras (see the [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/issues/92) and [pull request](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/pull/94) on GitHub). As of Apr 8, 2019, this commit is not released yet, so you have to install from `master`.

Comment: I commented out this exception as specified [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/pull/94/files). The model now tries to load ([here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet.py#L291)) the weights for the specified size which do not exist. It seems to me that [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/8a1e4d427999c26d1a1988dda45454769c4372a5/keras_applications/mobilenet.py#L206) should also be removed and the warning message should be updated. I will create an issue on Github.

Comment: The problem was resolved by [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/pull/101) pull request.

Answer (score 4):

To use custom image size in MobileNet, download weights form this link: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/tag/v0.6

But make sure which weights you need because it contains different weights files according to the research paper of [MobileNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf), as each model is dependent on the parameters `alpha` and `depth_multiplier`. There are four different values for `alpha`: 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0. Also, `depth_multiplier` is 1 according to this implementation of [mobilenet](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet.py). I would recommend that you download [`mobilenet_1_0_224_tf.h5`](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.6/mobilenet_1_0_224_tf.h5). It has the highest ImageNet accuracy among all according to [research paper Table 7](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf).

After that,

```py
from keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet

feature_model = MobileNet(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(200, 200, 3), alpha=1.0, depth_multiplier=1)
feature_model.load_weights('mobilenet_1_0_224_tf.h5') # give the path for downloaded weights
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: It looks like at the moment `input_shape` specifies two different things: the input shape used during training (and therefore the weights to load) and the input shape of the model being created. Anyway, your solution should work, thanks.

Comment: Update: the problem roots in the [unnecessary exception](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/pull/94/files) as @Soroush pointed out. For a custom size not in [128, 160, 192, 224], the default size of 224 is used (and the corresponding weights are loaded).

Comment: Yes! It's unnecessary exception. But It is not released yet. So, If not want to build from master than I had just shown you the approch according to current release.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks!