# How to create a custom image dataset in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create an image classifier using Estimators and or Keras.

I have been following the tutorial on this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images.

And I have built a Dataset of images and labels using this code:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((all_image_paths, all_image_labels))

image_label_ds = ds.map(load_and_preprocess_from_path_label)
```

image_label_ds outputs as this:

```
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((180, 360, 3), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>
```

Since the tutorial uses a MobileNetV2 that accepts images of size (192,192,3) I cannot follow this tutorial any longer.

Can someone explain to me how I can perform all the necessary preparation to the dataset and feed it into a DNNClassifier Premade Estimator?

Comment: your problem is only with the size of images? or something else?

Comment: No, I need help feeding my dataset into an Estimator

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571664/mobilenets-for-a-custom-image-size

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear, why can't you continue following the tutorial?

anyways,if the issue is the different input size, so in the tutorial you define the input shape for the network:

```
mobile_net = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(192, 192, 3), include_top=False)
```

try to define the input_shape for the network to the image size that you use - (180, 360, 3)